# How can I keep track of the programs that have been used to edit a file?

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to generate a record of each program that I used to modify each file on my computer, but so far, I haven't found a way to keep track of the files that have been modified by each program.

In Windows 7, is it possible to find which files were edited using a specific program? For example, would it be possible to generate a list of all files that were recently edited using Notepad or Microsoft Word?

Alternatively, is it possible to keep track of all programs that were used to modify one specific file?

Answer (score 0):

[Sysinternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default)

[Process Monitor v3.05](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)

[Process Explorer v15.31](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)

You will need to create filters that file sizes would not be very large. And some less, Procmon will run all the time, if you need a full report on the action.

Accordingly, it is always possible to run the application as a service.

Comment: What do you mean by "create filters that file sizes would not be very large"?

Comment: Also, which of these three tools would be able to keep track of the programs that have edited a file? Will I need to choose one of these three programs, or will I need to use all of them at the same time?

Comment: @AndersonGreen In the default saved all the events occurring in the system. The filter removes unwanted data. As I understand it you need only that the user is editing. Something like this.

Comment: I'm still confused. What do you mean by "in the default saved all the events occurring in the system"?

Comment: @AndersonGreen There are event-driven model of message flow in operating systems such as Microsoft. And subsystem with hardware WMI. That's about these events and stored. Your need Process Monitor.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: Run Process Monitor and you'll understand what he's trying to say. The window will quickly be filled up with various events as they occur in real-time, including files/registry keys being accessed/opened/written to/closed etc. What you'll need to do so as not be overwhelmed is define your own filters to filter out events you're not interested in, and focus solely on those that you are interested in tracking further.